# Autosize vuetify textarea to value-size

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want the textarea to be just as big as the `value`content. 
currently the textarea is standard size and I have to scroll to see the whole `value`content

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md6 lg4 pt-5 pb-5>
                    <v-textarea
                      auto-grow
                      label="Comments"
                      id="comment"
                      counter
                      :value="props.item.SurveyResults[0].comment"
                    ></v-textarea>
                  </v-flex>
```

Comment: Reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com/).

Comment: Here is the reproduce: 
down vote
accept
If what you want to perform is one row by default until you increase to more rows this is how to do: https://codepen.io/Helene-Andre/pen/OrWgyz?editors=1010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If what you want to perform is one row by default until you increase to more rows this is how to do: https://codepen.io/Helene-Andre/pen/OrWgyz?editors=1010

Just adding the attribute `rows="1"`

**VUE TEMPLATE**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-textarea rows="1"
                      auto-grow
                      label="Comments"
                      id="comment"
                      counter
                      :value="comment"
                    ></v-textarea>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    comment: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus non itaque possimus dicta sunt dolorem cum est autem reprehenderit architecto! Autem, aperiam, magni. Mollitia dolorum modi, tempora enim vero deserunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus non itaque possimus dicta sunt dolorem cum est autem reprehenderit architecto! Autem, aperiam, magni. Mollitia dolorum modi, tempora enim vero deserunt."
  })
})
```

Comment: so i need to know how many rows my value got? is is possible to give rows the attribute "auto" ?

Comment: No you don't need to, I updated the codepen, vuetify calculates it by itself!